# First Order Logic interpretation of: "If $f$ is continuous at $a$, then there is a number $δ \gt 0$ such that $f$ is bounded above on $(a-δ,a+δ)$"

Tags: real-analysis

In chapter 8 of Spivak's *Calculus*, the following theorem ("THEOREM 1") is posited on page 136:

> If $f$ is continuous at $a$, then there is a number $\delta \gt 0$ such that $f$ is bounded above in the interval $(a-\delta, a+ \delta)$

The proof is straightforward. Subsequently, I was interested in constructing the **contrapositive** version of this statement and wanted to make sure I was setting up the problem correctly. My usual routine for doing this (to ensure that everything is properly negated) is to write a pseudo-FOL interpretation of my statements.

SO, for "THEOREM 1", I have the following:

> $f$ is continuous at $a \rightarrow \exists \delta \gt 0 \text{ s.t. } \exists N \in \mathbb R \text{ s.t. } \forall x \in (a - \delta, a+ \delta) \Big [ f(x) \leq N\Big ]$

And then for the contrapositive, I have:

> $\forall \delta \gt 0 \ \forall N \in \mathbb R \  \exists x \in (a - \delta, a+ \delta) \text{ s.t. } \Big [ f(x) \gt N\Big ] \rightarrow $ $f$ is not continuous at $a$

Assuming this is the proper translation, is the correct interpretation of this contrapositive something along the lines of:

"If you have (vertical) asymptotes that appear in every neighborhood that can be constructed around $a$, then $f$ is not continuous at $a$"

Cheers~

Comment: Your contrapositive is correct. In words, you could say: If $f$ is not bounded from above in any interval $(a-\delta,a+\delta),\ \delta>0$, then $f$ is not continuous in $a$. You should not refer to asymptotes as $f$ can be unbounded without having asymptotes.

Comment: @StefanAlbrecht thank you for the input. Could you please provide an example of an interval $(a,b)$ for $a,b \in \mathbb R$ being unbounded without having asymptotes?

Comment: Consider $f:[-1,1]\to\mathbb R$ with $f(\frac1n)=n$ for $n\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. You can use your contrapositive to prove that $f$ is not continuous in $0$. However, for $n\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$, $x=\frac1n$ is not an asymptote, since $\lim_{x\to\frac1n}f(x)=0\neq\pm\infty$.

Comment: I would also say $f:[-1,1]\to\mathbb R$ given by $f(x)=x \sin(\pi/x)$ for $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$. The function is unbounded near $x=0$, but oscillates (in particular $f(1/n)=0\;\forall n$), so it doesn't go to $\pm\infty$.

Comment: @LorenzoPompili you probably mean $f(x)=\frac1x\sin(\frac\pi x)$, right? The function as stated is continuous.

Comment: Sure, thank you :)